# Given $a,b\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $b>\frac{a^4}{a^2+1}$, prove $b\geq a^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, functional-inequalities

> Given that
> $$ a,b \in \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \}$$
> and
> $$b> \frac{a^4}{a^2+1}$$
> How can I prove $b\geq a^2$ since I'm looking for all possible values of $(a,b)$ (and I actually know all though by some brute force) ?

So far I can go to the canonical form of the original inequality is this

$$b> a^2-1+ \frac{1}{a^2+1}.$$

Any help will be much appreciated :)

PS: I already solve this the way I wanted and I've seen my mistakes as well. Thanks to all who helped me and who edited my problem especially to @quasi. I'm SO satisfied rn since it's actually part of a more intricate probabilistic problem. I know it's kind of unfair but I'm more comfortable of my own solution and I put it below...

Comment: Thank you @MPW for editing.

Comment: How do you get $b>a^2?$ For example, $a=b=1$ satisfies the first inequality.

Comment: if you take a=b=1 don't you have b=a^2 and your inequality is satisfied?

Comment: $-1+\frac {1} {a^2 +1}$ is a small difference like it won't affect after all (by some brute force).

Comment: Since I want an elegant solution. I want to do it in casework, but how??

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. I'm going to analyze everything first to give more genuine reaction to your solutions. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s use contradiction. Suppose $b\leq a^{2}-1$.

$b\leq a^{2}-1$

$b(a^{2}+1)\leq (a^{2}-1)(a^{2}+1)$

$b\leq \frac{a^{4}-1}{a^{2}+1}$

Contradicting $b>\frac{a^{4}}{a^{2}+1}$

Comment: The negation of $b>a^2$ is $b\le a^2$

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to use contradiction in this kind of case yet, and never have I thought it can be used here. Thank you for showing me another way of solving it. Probably next time I'm going to learn this.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the comments, you can't prove $b > a^2$ since for the case $a=b=1$, the inequality
$$b > \frac{a^4}{a^2+1}$$
holds but the inequality $b > a^2$ fails.

But to prove $b\ge a^2$ holds for all the cases, we can argue as follows . . .
\begin{align*}
&b > \frac{a^4}{a^2+1}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b > \frac{a^4-1}{a^2+1}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b > \frac{(a^2+1)(a^2-1)}{a^2+1}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b > a^2-1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b \ge (a^2-1)+1\;\;\;\;\text{[since $b$ and $a^2-1$ are both integers]}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b \ge a^2
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you SO SOmuch @quasi your previous comment thought me everything I needed. Though it took me a while to comprehend it. I now have my own solution here please check it. Thanks again.

Comment: @hansduran0123: Yes, your answer is fine.

Comment: Yes. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\dfrac{a^4}{a^2+1}$.
$$A=\dfrac{a^4}{a^2+1}<\dfrac{a^4}{a^2}=a^2 \text{ and }b>A$$
Thus you need to show that $b\notin (A,a^2)$.

$a^2$ is an integer and $a^2-A=a^2-\dfrac{a^4}{a^2+1}=\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+1}<1$.
Thus the interval $(A,a^2)$ cannot contain an integer and $b\notin (A,a^2)$.
So $b\geq a^2$.

Comment: I actually struggled to comprehend your solution. Probably next time I'm going to learn this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I finally understand how to. This is how I did it (since I already know how to solve, I didn't put words on it).

$$ b > \frac {a^4}{a^2 +1}$$

$$\frac {a^4}{a^2 +1} = a^2 - 1 + \frac {1}{a^2 +1}$$

$$b >  a^2 - 1 + \frac {1}{a^2 +1}$$

$$b >  a^2 - 1 + \frac {1}{a^2 +1} > a^2 - 1$$

$$b > a^2 - 1$$

$$b \geq a^2 - 1 +1$$

$$b \geq a^2$$ .